# set padding right only for the firt line in textarea with css

Tags: css

i want to add a padding in the right of the first line of textarea. something like: "text-indent" in the right side. is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why only the first line? Can you give a example, with the code you have tried already?

Comment: i have an icon with absolute position on the top right of the textarea. i dont want the text to be hidden by this icon.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you could set a `padding: 10px 10px 0px 0px;` for top and right but that would effect whole textarea.

Comment: http://www.ironspider.ca/graphics/alignment.htm